# Where to put a function called from app.conponent.html

Tags: function, angular

I want to call a function when an image is clicked. I googled the problem and found I needed to use ng-click but could not find where to put the function's code.

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>"{{productGroup.groupName}}" Images</h2>
<img src="{{productGroup.imageUrl}}" ng-click="showDetails()">
<img src="{{productGroup2.imageUrl}}" ng-click="showDetails()">
```

I have tried the most obvious app.component.ts with no luck. One problem I am having with Angular 2 is a lot of examples/tutorials are out of date.  I am using the latest nodejs, angular 2 and angular-cli. Please help.

Comment: `ng-click` is angular 1.x way of doing things.

`(click)` is angular 2 way  of doing things.

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? BTW, the official docs are perfectly up to date. Which you should read to bone up on very basic things, such as how to associate a click handler with an element (hint: it's **not** `ng-click`).

Comment: torazaburo: I should not have used a used a colloquialism, in this case it meant I was unable to get it to work. I tried to "bone up on it" (which in your case I believe meant research). I did try, I googled but there were so many responses I was unable to find the documentation I required. BTW I did not want someone to write my code for me but just to point me in the right direction which Aakash Thakur was kind enough to do. Think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function in the Component class like:

```
export class YourComponent{
        showDetails(){
         //your code here
       }
       //Rest of the code
}
```

Call it in the template with:

```
<img src="{{productGroup.imageUrl}}" (click)="showDetails()">
```

In case you find problems, refer to the latest https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/ docs and you can find all relevant info there.

Comment: A very helpful reply, knowing what to look and where to look is half the problem.